# How can I create an encrypted container on a Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, security

I'm looking for a tool similar to Veracrypt, Boxcryptor or Cryptomator which runs on the Raspberry Pi 4 (armv8). The above mentioned apps don't seem to support the arm architecture (or at least not v8).
I want to create an encrypted container file which I could mount when needed and put files in it. Needs to run without network access.

Comment: What do you mean with **container** file? Do you want to use it as operating-system-level virtualization method using container like LXC (Linux Containers)? Or just meaning an encrypted file that mount will decrpyt?

Answer (score 3):

encfs is supported

```
apt install encfs
```

Answer (score 1):

Veracrypt does support ARM: check out [Contributed Resources](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Contributed%20Resources.html). The Pi 4 can run ARMv7 code just fine.

Of course, you can always build an open-source program for any CPU architecture you like, e.g. ARMv8. Since Pi 4 CPU [does not support](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243410) the AES extensions (`armv8-a+crypto`), making an ARMv8 Veracrypt build will not achieve anything in terms of performance, besides ruining compatibility with ARMv7.